# Adding product SKU into existing Cart Price rule Magento 1.7.0.2

Tags: magento-1.7, shopping-cart-price-rules, sku

I want to add/remove applicable product sku to/from already defined price rules programmatically when ever it is needed.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made it work like this. But still dont know how to remove the condition for a certain sku. This is my code:

```
$productId = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product')->getIdBySku($sku);
if($productId){
    $realProduct = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);
    $parentIds = Mage::getResourceSingleton('catalog/product_type_configurable')->getParentIdsByChild($realProduct->getId());
    $configProduct = Mage::getModel("catalog/product")->load($parentIds[0]);
    if(!$voucherRule->getConditions()->validate($realProduct)){
        $item_found = Mage::getModel('salesrule/rule_condition_product_found')
            ->setType('salesrule/rule_condition_product_found')
            ->setValue(1) // 1 == FOUND
            ->setAggregator('any'); // match ANY conditions
        $skuCondition = Mage::getModel('salesrule/rule_condition_product')
            ->setType('salesrule/rule_condition_product')
            ->setAttribute('sku')
            ->setOperator('==')
            ->setValue($realProduct->getSku());

        try{
            $voucherRule->getConditions()->addCondition($item_found);
            $item_found->addCondition($skuCondition);
            $voucherRule->save();
        }
        catch (Exception $e) {
            die($e->getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```